# SQL Studio query doesnt result nothing

Tags: marketing-cloud, appexchange, sql, sql-studio

I am quite confused because any query I run in SQL Studio results 0 records but apparently its success. See screenshot below.

[image]

I just basically want to retrieve the number of email address per email domain are in that data extension. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try running your query on the one line. I've had weird behavior when I copy/paste my query in the editor.

Comment: Agreed. There are some issues with copy/pasted queries.

Comment: You are both right, I just put everything in one line and retyping some code manually and it works. This is too funny

Comment: Great, I've posted this as an answer so it will be easy for others to notice. Can you mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your query on one line. I've had weird behavior when I copy/paste my query in the editor.